# How to Merge Rows with Same Name SQL Pivot

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot, distinct

I am trying to denormalize some data in SQL Server and have been able to successfully pivot a reference table, but would like to be able to merge like rows.

The pivot is executed as follows

```
select distinct 
'name' = sFname + ' ' + sLname,
advanced, 
basic, 
standard

from
(select * from dbName..person where deleteFlag <> 'Y') as tableTemp
pivot (
  count(serviceType)
  for serviceType IN (advanced, basic, standard)
) as tablePivot
```

And returns

```
name      | advanced | basic | standard
----------+----------+-------+---------
abby a    |     1    |   0   |    0
abby a    |     0    |   1   |    0
charlie c |     0    |   1   |    0
charlie c |     0    |   0   |    1
```

But I would like to return in this form

```
name      | advanced | basic | standard
----------+----------+-------+---------
abby a    |     1    |   1   |    0
charlie c |     0    |   1   |    1
```

The original data is structured like

```
sFname   | sLname   | serviceType |
---------+----------+-------------+
abby     |     a    |   advanced  |
abby     |     a    |   basic     |
charlie  |     c    |   basic     |
charlie  |     c    |   standard  |
```

How can I run an operation like `group by` or `select distinct` to return a consolidated pivoted table in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the columns in your subquery before the `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT [name], 
       [advanced], 
       [basic], 
       [standard]
FROM   (
           SELECT 'name' = sFname + ' ' + sLname, 
                  serviceType
           FROM   person
           WHERE  deleteFlag <> 'Y'
       ) AS tableTemp 
PIVOT(COUNT(serviceType) FOR serviceType IN(advanced, basic, standard)) AS tablePivot;
```